# Efficiently collapsing rows in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following toy data.frame:

```
> df
  Fragments   a    b    c    d    e
1       0.5 0.2 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20
2       1.5 0.2 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20
3      22.0 0.4 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
4       5.1 0.6 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10
5       4.2 0.4 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
6      10.0 0.6 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10
```

and I'd like to collapse it by rows in which all but the first column are identical (i.e., columns "a" to "e" in this example) and taking the sum over the first column (the "Fragments" column in this example) in these collapsed row. So the result will be this data.frame:

```
> collpased.df
  Fragments   a    b    c    d    e
1       2.0 0.2 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20
2      26.2 0.4 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
3      15.1 0.6 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10
```

I'm looking for the most efficient solution as in my real data the number of rows and columns is very large. The aggregate function seems too slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as Jilber says if you know the **data.table** package. If not, just use 
`aggregate()`.

```
result = aggregate(df[,1],df[,-1],sum)
```

In this case the result will end up in the last column.

EDIT: You state that `aggregate()` is too slow. The main problem that you will have with `data.table` is that the initialization cost of `data.table(df)` is quite big, so you need to amortize it. Casting a data.table only for that operation and nothing else, is just not worth it.

So my advice stays the same. If you know the package **and** you will use its potential several times during the session then use it. If not, stick to `aggregate()`.

Comment: +1. I personally prefer the `formula` syntax though: `aggregate(Formula ~ ., df, sum)`

Answer (score 1):

If you already tried using `aggregate` and found it *too slow*, then you might want to try `data.table` from data.table package.

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(df)
> dt[,list(Fragments=sum(Fragments)), by=list(a,b,c,d,e)]
     a    b    c    d    e Fragments
1: 0.2 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20       2.0
2: 0.4 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15      26.2
3: 0.6 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10      15.1
```